# Android app rotates orientation once but crashes on second rotation

Tags: android-intent, android-orientation

I am creating an android app with two orientations. I can open up in landscape and switch to portrait, but if I try flipping back to landscape, the app crashes. The portrait activity class extends FragmentActivity whereas the landscape class extends Activity. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java(old):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        return;
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(this, PortActivity.class));
}
}
```

MainActivity.java(new):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

PortActivity.java(new OnCreate):

```
public class PortActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;//The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_port);
etc(same as before)....
```

PortActivity.java(old OnCreate):

```
public class PortActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;//The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_port);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_port_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.mathapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mathapp.PortActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

log file:

```
02-17 14:29:53.704: W/ResourceType(3223): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030001 (t=2 e=1) 

in package 0 (error -75)
02-17 14:29:53.714: D/AndroidRuntime(3223): Shutting down VM
02-17 14:29:53.724: W/dalvikvm(3223): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb501c180)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathapp/com.example.mathapp.PortActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1018)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2105)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at com.example.mathapp.PortActivity.onCreate(PortActivity.java:50)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-17 14:29:53.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3223):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Please add the crash stack trace, "the app crashes" is not very informative. Also please add your Android manifest to see how are you declaring the activities, since I find it odd that you have 2 classes for the same activity. Also, have you used the debugger to step through the code to see what's going on?

Comment: @frozenkoi, I added the manifest and log containing the crash details. I will test out the debugger now.

Comment: The exception thrown is `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001` Check that cleaning and rebuilding your project fixes the issue. If not, verify that resource 0x7f030001 exists in the generated gen/R.java and if so it'll give you a better clue to what resource is related to the problem.

Comment: @frozenkoi, that is the ID for activity_port, which is the layout that PortActivity.class is loading.

Comment: since the exception is thrown when PortActivity goes from portrait to landscape, check that the layout exists for landscape, and it doesn't have errors.

Comment: @frozenkoi, please see my edit. Now my problem is the portrait orientation is blank (but no crashing). Am I missing something?

Comment: Your main issue is that you're using two `activity` classes for 1 activity (in the philosophical sense), splitting the functionality between two chunks of code. What's happening in this particular case is this. (1) you start your activity (`MainActivity`) in landscape, it passes the `if` and loads the layout. you then (2) rotate the screen. the activity is re-created. This time it doesn't pass the `if` and instead opens a second `Activity` (`PortActivity`). Then (3) you rotate back to landscape. So `PortActivity` is re-created. And it's not designed to support this scenario.

Comment: You should look into supporting multiple screen configurations with a single `Activity`. In your case start by having one same layout name for both orientations, one in res/layout and the other in res/layout-land and have the code handle each one. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-layouts could be a good starting point, it has some parts about orientation (also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html & http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources )